# Cómo extraer fila con condicional de mínimo valor en columna?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, anaconda, spyder

estoy comenzando con python y tengo una duda si es que me pueden ayudar
Tengo 1000 archivos ".odt" y cada archivo tiene 6 columnas (todas las columnas sin nombres).

Pero necesito analizar la columna numero 6 y buscar la celda que tienen el menor valor de toda esa columna. Una vez que la identifique necesito extraer la fila completa e ir juntandolas en un nuevo archivo

por ejemplo para 2 archivos (pero son 1000 en verdad)

Archivo 1.odt :

col1  col 2  col 3  col4  col5  col6

a     b      c       d     e     10

**x     y      z       w     h     6**

---

Archivo 2.odt :

col1  col 2  col 3  col4  col5  col6

**a     b      c       d     e     1**

x     y      z       w     h     6

---

Dejarlo en un archivo final llamado "final.csv" y deberia quedar asi

**x     y      z       w     h     6**

**a     b      c       d     e     1**

Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradeceria muchisimo

Comment: Que has intentado o investigado?

Comment: Hola, primero  estoy intentando convertir 1 archivo odt a matriz (guiandome por https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/python/cargar-datos-de-txt-con-pandas/1043629051/)

Luego tengo pensando usar un condicional para la columna (guiandome por https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/)

Pero eso seria para un archivo

Comment: Tengo una duda. ¿Los archivos .odt son de texto plano o son de algún formato especial? Entiendo que los usa OpenOffice (LibreOffice) para almacer documentos. ¿Cómo se ven si los abres con Notepad o un editor de texto simple?

Comment: Si tienen columnas, están separados por comas (.csv). Al menos eso creo @CandidMoe

Comment: @EduardoSaavedra, creo que lo mejor es pasar los archivos a dataframes y trabajarlos, luego concatenar en axis = 1 (para que sea horizontal o 0 para vertical) las filas deseadas. Finalmente usar `to_csv()` para guardar el archivo .csv. Obviamente todo desde la librería Pandas, creo que es lo más apropiado.

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/T8xCHADC#fbQzEzISS62o70IB1OxPQYfgT1hk8jbFLv3BTWXgcag   

https://mega.nz/file/TshC1IaB#awPw8FMlTNyeaVMsrwTkwg85PfqVTBrmULR0OElKcWI

en cada enlace hay un archivo odt que me entrega un programa de calculo.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agreagar lo que has tratado o investigado, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion en la pregunta, no como comentario...

Answer (score 0):

PUDE REALIZAR EL CODIGO Y ME ENTREGA UN ARCHIVO CSV POR CADA ODT

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys


def extraerodtcol(base):
    path,dirs,files=os.walk(base).__next__()
    
    
    for i in range(len(files)):
        df = pd.read_csv(path+'\\'+files[i],names=['A','B','C','D','E','F'], skiprows=12, delim_whitespace=True)
        only=df[df.F == df.F.min()]
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
        np.savetxt(base+"\\"+str(files[i])+".csv", only,delimiter=',', fmt="%s")
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=-sys.maxsize-1)
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? podrias explicar un poco mas? mira por favor [answer]